# Get sharp fonts on pc and mac?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have problems with the fonts on my website to have skarp fonts on both mac and pc. The fonts look sharp on Mac, but on PC the fonts are very dull and thin.

Is there something specific in CSS I can do to avoid the problem with PC?

[Screenhshot from mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjA2q.jpg)

[Screenshot from PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtB4V.jpg)

Comment: Which kind of fonts are you using? Custom fonts or font service fonts (google fonts, typekit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer this question, because there are a lot of different factors which influence font rendering.

1. The font itself. Is it a screen font, by means of hinting and other special optimisation for pixel based display. The font you have showed in the image looks very thin, what is always problematic in small sizes.
2. Font rendering is done by the OS, not by the browser, so there are always differences in the final displayed rendering.

In my experience, 98% of such cases appear if one tries to use a print font in relatively small sizes. If the font is thin in cut, problems grow.

To overcome those issues, I recommend to use screen optimized fonts (aka webfonts), those can be provided for free from google fonts etc. or bought. If it still does not look good, try bigger sizes and if that is not option, it might be the wrong font of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use Font rendering (https://davidwalsh.name/font-smoothing):

```
body {
       -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
       -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```